# ASP.Net Background Music

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, background-music

I have a website with a master page and I want to play an mp3 file in the background, in every page.

tried bgmusic but its not supported and so is embed.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do it. One of the most annoying things in the world is music on a webpage.  If absolutely MUST embed an MP3, please, please, please, provide a way for the user to turn it off and/or mute it.

that being said, [here](http://www.suite101.com/content/how-to-put-mp3-file-in-web-page-a46092) is an article with a couple of ways to play an MP3 on your page.

Comment: Its a school project so its not really anoyying anyone. It'll just impress the teacher

Comment: if its homework you should add the homework tag

Answer (score 3):

*(mandatory xkcd reference, CW because it's not a real answer)*

[image: It's like they got together and said 'what do we miss most from the internet in 1998? that's right, embedded MIDI!']

Alt-text: *It's like they got together and said 'what do we miss most from the internet in 1998?  that's right, embedded MIDI!'*

([link](http://www.xkcd.com/134/))

*Too short, didn't understand it*: don't do it, it's fastidious on just about every level: you waste *your* bandwidth, you waste *user's* bandwidth, you waste user's PC resources to run a plugin (be it Flash or whatever), you make browsing between pages slower (because the music has to be started each time), but, most important, you make the users of your site hate it because 99% of them just want to read the darn pages and do not care at all about your music.